# How to reenable Unity 3D after installing Bumblebee?

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee

I installed Bumblebee to solve Nvidia/Intel driver problem. It does work well, but it also disabled Unity 3D.

How can I get my Unity 3D back?

Comment: did you installed anything like ironhide before. have you installed bumblebee from here ? http://www.bumblebee-project.org/install.html#Ubuntu

Comment: Make sure you don't have nvidia-common installed.  The only nvidia packages that should be installed are nvidia-current and bumblebee-nvidia

Comment: Ian B. when uninstalling nvidia-common, synaptic also wants to un-install the ubuntu-desktop-system. Are you sure this is wise?

Answer (score 2):

Bumblebee is pretty unstable right now, especially in 12.04.

Nvidia drivers a pretty solid, even if they aren't open sourced. I recommend sticking to the official driver. I installed Bumblebee on a 9800GT and it took out my whole xserver.

use

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia nvidia-current
```

and download the official driver from nvidia:
http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

Answer (score 0):

After your computer is up an running, logout of your current session. On the login screen there is a little icon you need to click (near the user name). From the icon menu, you should be able select Unity 3D, or any other installed desktops.

Answer (score 0):

You should uninstall bumblebee, bumblebee-nvidia and nvidia-current.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia nvidia-current
```

It should not be necessary to uninstall nvidia-common nor ubuntu-desktop-system.